# Checkbox dinamico que importa colunas de tabelas no mysql

Tags: javascript

Uso uma biblioteca mpdf pra gerar pdf consultando meu banco de dados.Tenho que adicionar colunas dinamicamente nesse pdf usando checkbox.A cada caixa marcada adiciona uma coluna especifica no meu pdf e se desmarca é pra sumir.Gostaria de saber como faço isso ..de preferençia usando javascript.

---

```
<?php
require_once './conexao.php';

$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM eventos';
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$dados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Eventos Sinpro-df</title>
    </head>
    <body>



        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; margin:2px ; border-collapse">
            <tr> <th> <a href="http://www.sinprodf.org.br/" target="_Blank" title="Clique aqui e visite nossa página"><img src="./images.jpg" height="200 px" width="423px"/></a> </th></tr>

        </table>


        Escolha seu evento:<br>
        <select name="eventos" id="eventos">
            <option value=""> </option>


            <?php
            foreach ($dados as $value) {

                echo "<option value='$value->id'>$value->nome</option>";
            }
            ?>

        </select>

        <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="javascript: gerar();" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cencelar"/>

    </body>




<script type="text/javascript">



    function gerar() {

        var evento = document.getElementById("eventos").value;
        location.href = "./teste.php?id=" + evento;


    }


</script>



<br/><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Telefone"/> Creche<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Celular"/>Celular<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Email"/>Email<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Creche"/>Creche<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Necessidade"/>Necessidade<br/>
<br/>


</html>
```

parte do meu codigo. Esse é uma pagina que seleciona tabelas e gera em pdf usando o mpdf e já tem as caixas de seleçao(chekbox)que quero usar para pegar as coluna do banco e deixar no pdf dinamicamente...